# Why does Rust need the `if let` syntax?

Tags: rust, option-type

Coming from other functional languages (and being a Rust newbie), I'm a bit surprised by the motivation of Rust's `if let` syntax. The [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/160) mentions that without `if let`, the "idiomatic solution today for testing and unwrapping an `Option<T>`" is either

```
match opt_val {
    Some(x) => {
        do_something_with(x);
    }
    None => {}
}
```

or

```
if opt_val.is_some() {
    let x = opt_val.unwrap();
    do_something_with(x);
}
```

In Scala, it would be possible to do exactly the same, but the idiomatic solution is rather to `map` over an `Option` (or to `foreach` if it is only for the side effect of `doing_something_with(x)`).

Why isn't it an idiomatic solution to do the same in Rust?

```
opt_val.map(|x| do_something_with(x));
```

Comment: How do you do such thing in Scala: `if let Some(foo) = bar { ... } else if let Some(foo) = baz { ... } else if let Some(foo) = daz { ... } else { ... }`? Using map/flatMap seems very nested: `bar.map(...).orElse(baz.map(...).orElse(daz.map(...))).getOrElse(...)`

Comment: @fantom: For instance: `List(bar, baz, daz).find(_.isDefined).foreach(println(_))`

Comment: yeah, if you need to perform the same action in each branch, but what if they are different (not `println` for each)? I faced this issue recently and didn't found any way better than nested map/orElse

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`.map()` is specific to the `Option<T>` type, but `if let` (and `while let`!) are features that work with all Rust types.

Comment: Note: I accept this answer because it briefly summarizes the main _technical_ difference, but see @Vladimir's answer for a more comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score 30):

`map()` is intended for *transforming* an optional value, while `if let` is mostly needed to perform *side effects*. While Rust is not a pure language, so any of its code blocks can contain side effects, map semantics is still there. Using `map()` to perform side effects, while certainly possible, will only confuse readers of your code. Note that it should not have performance penalties, at least in simple code - LLVM optimizer is perfectly capable of inlining the closure directly into the calling function, so it turns to be equivalent to a `match` statement.

Before `if let` the only way to perform side effects on an `Option` was either a match or `if` with `Option::is_some()` check. `match` approach is the safest one, but it is very verbose, especially when a lot of nested checks are needed:

```
match o1 {
    Some(v1) => match v1.f {
        Some(v2) => match some_function(v2) {
            Some(r) => ...
            None => {}
        }
        None => {}
    }
    None => {}
}
```

Note the prominent rightward drift and a lot of syntactical noise. And it only gets worse if branches are not simple matches but proper blocks with multiple statements.

`if option.is_some()` approach, on the other hand, is slightly less verbose but still reads very badly. Also its condition check and `unwrap()` are not statically tied, so it is possible to get it wrong without the compiler noticing it.

`if let` solves the verbosity problem, based on the same pattern matching infrastructure as `match` (so it is harder to get wrong than `if option.is_some()`) and, as a side benefit, allows using arbitrary types in patterns, not only `Option`. For example, some types may not provide `map()`-like methods; `if let` will still work with them very nicely. So `if let` is a clear win, hence it is idiomatic.

Comment: _Using `map` to perform side effects will only confuse readers of your code._ That is why Scala always offers two versions of `map`, one for transformation and one for side-effects. What I like about the Scala approach is that it solves the same problem without introducing additional syntax. Expect Scala users to `map` over `Options` a lot :) (it is ubiquitous in Scala).

Comment: @bluenote10, I'm writing Scala for a living, so I'm perfectly aware of that :) Again, note that `if let` works *not only for `Option`*, and the syntax is arguably more lightweight than with closures.

Comment: Should it be mentioned here that if `map` causes you to move out of a shared reference, `map` is potentially less desirable than `if let` since it would require an additional `as_ref()`? That is at least 50% of the reason why I never get to use `map` in Rust.

Answer (score 4):

A quote from [a related issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/book/issues/1401#issuecomment-450628967) against *The Rust Programming Language*:

> You'd better think about `if let` as a one-handed `match` with no exhaustive checking enforced. It often has nothing to do with `if` or `let`, that's why it is so confusing. :)
>
> Maybe it would be better to rename the whole operator, call it `match once` or something like that.

(slightly modified to make sense without the context)

Comment: `if let` is also confusing for having the rvalue to the left of the lvalue.

Answer (score 3):

Because your solution creates a closure, which uses resources, whereas `if let` desugars exactly to your first example, which doesn't. I also find it more readable.

Rust is all about zero-cost abstractions that make programming nicer, and `if let` and `while let` are good examples of those (at least IMO -- I realize it's a matter of personal preference). They're not strictly necessary, but they sure feel good to use (also see: Clojure, where they were likely lifted from).

Comment: As I understand it, they were lifted from [Swift](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0160-if-let.md)

Comment: So in other words: Mapping is okay if it not performance critical? Considering that the `if let` syntax and the `map` are syntactically almost identical, I'm wondering if it would actually be possible for the optimizer to avoid creating a closure in the first place...

Comment: @bluenote10 with the new unboxed closures, `map` is actually just as fast as using a `match` statement and likely compiles to exactly the same code, as the closure is statically called and can be easily inlined.

Comment: Just to underline: `.map()` is a zero cost abstraction, too.