# What's the recommended way to produce side effects in control flow using Result?

Tags: rust, control-flow

[`Result::and_then()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then) works great for composing control flow.

```
fn some_fn() -> Result<String, Error> {
    Ok("Yay".to_string())
}
```

```
some_fn()
    .and_then(|value| some_other_fn())
    .and_then(|some_other_value| /* ... */)
```

Sometimes we want to create a side effect and still propagate the emitted value. Let's say we want to print the value the moment we receive it:

```
some_fn()
    .and_then(|value| {
        println!("{}", &value);
        some_other_fn()
    })
    .and_then(|some_other_value| /* ... */)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Something like [Reactive Extensions' `tap()` operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html) would be great.

Comment: *we want to print the value the moment we receive it* — but you still want to call `some_other_function`? If so, what's wrong with what you have?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm referring to.

Nothing's wrong with what I have. I'm just keeping eyes and ears open for more elegant solutions (if possible). Your answer makes perfect sense, as always - Thank you!

Comment: side effect are never elegant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`map` and `and_then` are appropriate for when you want to transform the value. Using `match` or `if let` is appropriate for side effects:

```
let r = some_fn();

if let Ok(v) = &r {
    println!("{}", v);
}

r.and_then(|_| some_other_fn())
```

See also:

- [Why does Rust need the `if let` syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27534364/155423)

*Assuming* that you only care about side effects when the `Result` is `Ok`...

You could also create an *extension trait* to add the desired method to `Result`. I'd advocate for calling it `inspect` as that's the name of [the parallel method on `Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.inspect).

```
trait InspectExt<T> {
    fn inspect<F>(self, f: F) -> Self
    where
        F: FnOnce(&T);
}

impl<T, E> InspectExt<T> for Result<T, E> {
    fn inspect<F>(self, f: F) -> Self
    where
        F: FnOnce(&T),
    {
        if let Ok(v) = &self {
            f(v)
        }
        self
    }
}
```

```
some_fn()
    .inspect(|v| println!("{}", v))
    .and_then(|_| some_fn())
```

See also:

- [Is there a way other than traits to add methods to a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33376486/155423)